# Why AutoMapper nested mapping works without CreateMap for inner type

Tags: c#, automapper

Model to AutoMap:

```cs
public class OuterSource
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public InnerSource Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerSource
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}

public class OuterDest
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDest
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

I found that if I comment out `CreateMap` for inner type.
Nested mapping still work. I would like to understand why it works, as it is not clearly stated in the documentation.

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
    // cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();    // <-- don't need this
});
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var source = new OuterSource
{
    Value = 5,
    Inner = new InnerSource {OtherValue = 15}
};
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dest = mapper.Map<OuterSource, OuterDest>(source);
```

Note: I use AutoMapper version 8.1.0

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at source code on github for Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/MapperConfiguration.cs#L112) we can easily see that it gets a `mapper` function from a `ConcurrentDictionary` by using `GetOrAdd` method. It means that if it doesnt exist in the cache it is created.

```
 public Delegate GetMapperFunc(MapRequest mapRequest) => _mapPlanCache.GetOrAdd(mapRequest).Typed;
```